# pandas_datareader keeps returning historical Yahoo FInance data only for last 12 months

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm following a portfolio optimization lecture on YouTube and writing the codes as it progresses (running Jupyter Notebook via VS Code), but stumbled upon an issue I just cannot manage to get fixed.

Below are the libraries I've imported:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

Then I've setup list of assets:

```
assets = ['FB', 'AMZN', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'GOOG']
```

After that, the portfolio starting date (returned value '2013-01-01'):

```
PortfStartDate = datetime(2013, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then, today's date (returned value '2022-07-04'):

```
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Please note we're dealing with a period that spans roughly 9 1/2 years...

An empty dataframe was created to store the fetched historical data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

And finally a loop code was setup to store for each asset in the list the fetched data only for the 'Adj Close' column onto the dataframe:

```
for portfolio in assets:
df[portfolio] = web.DataReader(portfolio, data_source = 'yahoo', start = PortfStartDate, end = today)['Adj Close']
```

And then when I run 'df' the returned dataset ALWAYS pertain only to the period spanning the last 12 months (Jul/2021 - Jun/2022) as shown on the screenshot below:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8vYp.png)

I've tried everything to my (limited) knowledge to have that corrected but to no avail. Changed dates, restarted VS Code, even rebooted the computer, but the code insists on only returning the last 12 months.

I've been running pandas_datareader recently in several other occasions and this issue never came up.

Here is my last resource, I hope someone can shed a light on this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out where the problem was...

I was using decommissioned tickers for Facebook, which as we all know is now META, therefore 'META' and no longer 'FB', and Google's (Alphabet's nowadays, also as we all know) ticker was missing an 'L' at the end.